# What will happen to the light due to frame-dragging?

Tags: black-holes, visible-light, geodesics, gravitational-lensing, frame-dragging

Imagine a rotating black hole is blocking a cluster of stars that I'm observing. Thanks to gravitational lensing I could still see the stars albeit shifted away from their original locations. So now what should these apparent stars look like to me taking the effect of frame dragging of the spinning black hole into account? Do they take different timings to reach me or the leeward one is slightly blue shifted and windward one redshifted? If black hole is observed spinning left to right, then leeward is refer to the left side while windward is the right side of the black-hole.

Comment: There is no red or blue shift. Photons don’t change energy while flying in a stationary gravitational field: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457995

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9x558j89Tjw